# Gridview - convert textboxcell to comboboxcell and back

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have a question about datagridviewcell.
i have created textboxcolumn in datagridview. when ever i click the particular cell the cell should change to datagridviewcomboboxcell. Also i need to add the item in combobox collection.
when i go to another cell then, the new cell get datagridviewcombobox cell and existing cell should change to datagridviewtextbox cell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` to `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` in the `CellBeginEdit` event and change it back in `CellEndEdit` event.

Try this:

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {   DataGridViewComboBoxCell cb=new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            cb.Items.Add(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value);
            //add your other itmes here;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = cb;//change the DataGridViewTextBoxCell to DataGridViewComboBoxCell 
        }

        delegate void settexthandler(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e); //use delegate to prevent reentrant call 

        private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.BeginInvoke(new settexthandler(settoTextBox), new object[] { e });           
        }

        void settoTextBox(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell tb = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

            tb.Value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = tb; //set it back to DataGridViewTextBoxCell with newly selected value 
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by *dropdown enabled*?