# Change Textboxcell to a Comboboxcell at run time

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm using MySQL .net connector to fill a Datagridview using `Mysqladapter` and `Datagridview.Bindingsource`. That works good, but I want to change one thing:

In the table which is filled to the DataGridview, there is a column with a text type. The cells in this columns are displayed as a `Datagridviewtextboxcell` in the datagridview, but I want to change it to `DataGridviewComboboxCell` (the users should select between ~10 items).

I already tried a lot but nothing worked as it should. The Columns in the DataGridview are readonly, I cannot change `DefaultCellTemplate` to a `DataGridviewComboboxCell`, cause it doesn't inherit `DataGridviewTextboxcell`.

I also tried this: [Gridview - convert textboxcell to comboboxcell and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533976/gridview-convert-textboxcell-to-comboboxcell-and-back) and I think my problem could be solved over this way, but with this solution I have also 1 problem: It doesnt show a DropDown Button.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want every single cell in this column to be a combobox, or only certain cells, with the rest remaining as text?

Comment: I want that every single cell in this column is a combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to add a new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to the grid and then hide the text box column.

I show this using code below but you can do the same using the designer (just set the properties I set in code using the designer).

The key things to note are:

- DataPropertyName refers to a property of the grid's data source - likely your text box source
- You need to provide the column with its own data source
- DisplayMember and ValueMember refer to the data source of the column

Here is the code to add the column:

```
// Here I do this in the form constructor - there are other places you can do it
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

    // You need to set some properties on the column to make it work

    // Datasource is the source (usually a list) of objects to show in the combobox
    col.DataSource = dataSource;

    col.DataPropertyName = "ColumnInGridDataSource";
    col.DisplayMember = "DisplayProperty";
    col.ValueMember = "ValueProperty";

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);

    // This hides the textboxcolumn
    dataGridView1.Columns["YourTextBoxColumnName"].Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: That would be propably not bad, but if I do tis like this, Updating using the `MySQLDataAdapter` doesnt work anymore.

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls Why doesn't it work? This code is designed to work with databinding - setting the DataPropertyName updates the backing data source and then you update with the dataadapter as before.

Comment: Ok that was probably my fail, I done C&P without changing DataPropertyName and the other Propertys. Will try it tomorrow again... Stupid Me (:

Comment: Ok it works, I dont knew what to put into `.DisplayMember` and `.ValueMember` , so I leave this out. For what usage are this properties and which value should I set into this properties?

Comment: These properties refer to the properties you want to use as the combobox displayed value (what it shows to users) and the actual value (what it uses to pass to the DataPropertyName column) Both refer to the column's datasource, not to the grid's datasource

Comment: Last question: I find it good how it is actually displayed, do i have to set those properties

Comment: You mean that the displayed property is already what you want? In that case don't bother - value property might be necessary, though again, if it all works, don't bother setting it.

Answer (score 1):

In the answer you linked, before the line:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] = cb;
```

Try adding:

```
cb.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.CHOOSE_ONE;
cb.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.CHOOSE_ONE;
```

I am not sure how exactly you want to style your comboboxes, so instead of "CHOOSE_ONE", try out the styles and pick the style you want.

**Edit**: Seems like you're not changing it to a combobox at all. Try this:

```
var values = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
cell.DataSource = values;
dataGridView1[col, row] = cell;
```

Comment: Thx, but it isnt working, i tried all display styles and flatstyles and it stills ends in this: http://s1.directupload.net/images/120905/q3jlcpfe.png

Comment: That does not look like a combobox to me at all. Check out the edit.